# Performance in apply-hops

Tags: sesam

I have a dataset with 3000 entites, which i hop to from another dataset with similar size. The performance has been poor, taking 15-20 minute for the pipe to complete.

My goal is to retrieve elements which are inside an interval of 15 minutes. Eg 16:45 and 17:00, which also is a match on asset and station.

How is

```
["apply-hops", "state", {
        "datasets": ["merge-operationiec mo"],
        "where": [
          ["eq", "_S.asset", "mo.asset"],
          ["eq", "_S.station", "mo.station"],
          ["gte",
            ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "mo.timestamp"],
            ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
          ],
          ["lt",
            ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "mo.timestamp"],
            ["datetime-plus", "minute", 15,
              ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is slow is that this hop will only do an index lookup on `merge-operationiec` for the `asset` equality. The rest of the matching is currently done by iterating over these entities which is slow if the initial lookup returned a lot of entities.

The recommended way for solving this is to use the `tuples` function. This builds up a composite index that removes the slow iteration.

However in this example there is a `gte` and `lt` clause which makes this harder. Currently indexes are not supported when doing these range clauses. In this case we can do a little manual optimization because we see that the range only operates on the current hour + 15 minutes. We can therefore create a time window that we then do the `gte` and `lt` operations on.

Given the following inputs:

```
{
  "_id": "timeseries-a-original",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "a1",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 00:45"
    }, {
      "_id": "a2",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 01:00"
    }, {
      "_id": "a3",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 01:15"
    }, {
      "_id": "a4",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 01:30"
    }]
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "_id": "merge-operationiec-original",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "b1",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 00:45",
      "value": "~f0.02"
    }, {
      "_id": "b2",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 01:00",
      "value": "~f0.04"
    }, {
      "_id": "b3",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 01:15",
      "value": "~f0.03"
    }, {
      "_id": "b4",
      "asset": "foo",
      "station": "bar",
      "timestamp": "2018-08-31 01:30",
      "value": "~f0.06"
    }]
  }
}
```

We can then add the time window (notice that we need to have a two hour window to solve this across the date boundary):

```
{
  "_id": "timeseries-a",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "timeseries-a-original"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["add", "time-window",
          ["list",
            ["datetime-format", "%Y-%m-%d %H",
              ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
            ],
            ["datetime-format", "%Y-%m-%d %H",
              ["datetime-plus", "hour", 1,
                ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the same for the other timeseries:

```
{
  "_id": "merge-operationiec",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "merge-operationiec-original"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["add", "time-window",
          ["list",
            ["datetime-format", "%Y-%m-%d %H",
              ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
            ],
            ["datetime-format", "%Y-%m-%d %H",
              ["datetime-plus", "hour", 1,
                ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

We can then optimize the hop you posted using tuples and the time window like this:

```
{
  "_id": "timeseries-join",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "timeseries-a"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "related",
          ["apply-hops", "state", {
            "datasets": ["merge-operationiec mo"],
            "where": [
              ["eq",
                ["tuples", "_S.asset", "_S.station", "_S.time-window"],
                ["tuples", "mo.asset", "mo.station", "mo.time-window"]
              ],
              ["gte",
                ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "mo.timestamp"],
                ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
              ],
              ["lt",
                ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "mo.timestamp"],
                ["datetime-plus", "minute", 15,
                  ["datetime-parse", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "_S.timestamp"]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }]
        ]
      ],
      "state": [
        ["copy", "*", "_*"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This should give the same result but be a lot faster.